# R ggplot - Can't allocate big vector

Tags: r, ggplot2, out-of-memory, geom-raster

I'm trying to plot a relatively small data set, and I can't get it to show me the plot. It keeps giving the error `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 9.7 Gb`. This doesn't make much sense to me as the data set is rather small.

```
> nrow(locs)
[1] 130
> head(locs)
       STATION AVGTRANGE     LAT     LONG
1: USC00286979  22.13333 40.6971 -75.2042
2: USC00360022  21.33333 40.5361 -79.8152
3: USC00360132  24.37037 40.5227 -78.3694
4: USC00360140  19.80000 40.4949 -78.4667
5: USC00360147  22.36667 41.3585 -77.9262
6: USC00360457  20.68000 40.8209 -76.4983
```

How I'm plotting it.

```
gg <- ggplot(data = locs, aes(x = LONG, y = LAT)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill=AVGTRANGE), interpolate=TRUE)
gg # can't allocate here
```

Here is the `dput` my data.

```
> dput(locs)
structure(list(STATION = structure(1:130, .Label = c("USC00286979", 
"USC00360022", "USC00360132", "USC00360140", "USC00360147", "USC00360457", 
"USC00360560", "USC00360656", "USC00360754", "USC00360785", "USC00360861", 
"USC00360868", "USC00361139", "USC00361212", "USC00361301", "USC00361350", 
"USC00361354", "USC00361362", "USC00361377", "USC00361480", "USC00361485", 
"USC00361705", "USC00361726", "USC00361751", "USC00361802", "USC00361810", 
"USC00361838", "USC00361920", "USC00362071", "USC00362183", "USC00362323", 
"USC00362470", "USC00362574", "USC00362721", "USC00362942", "USC00363018", 
"USC00363028", "USC00363226", "USC00363311", "USC00363321", "USC00363343", 
"USC00363417", "USC00363437", "USC00363451", "USC00363632", "USC00363665", 
"USC00363698", "USC00364214", "USC00364325", "USC00364432", "USC00364763", 
"USC00364778", "USC00364815", "USC00364839", "USC00364896", "USC00364934", 
"USC00364976", "USC00364992", "USC00365050", "USC00365109", "USC00365344", 
"USC00365573", "USC00365686", "USC00365738", "USC00365902", "USC00365918", 
"USC00366111", "USC00366151", "USC00366194", "USC00366238", "USC00366508", 
"USC00366649", "USC00366886", "USC00366921", "USC00366927", "USC00367029", 
"USC00367073", "USC00367103", "USC00367167", "USC00367186", "USC00367229", 
"USC00367409", "USC00367477", "USC00367732", "USC00367782", "USC00367863", 
"USC00367931", "USC00367938", "USC00368073", "USC00368184", "USC00368308", 
"USC00368361", "USC00368400", "USC00368449", "USC00368469", "USC00368596", 
"USC00368668", "USC00368868", "USC00368873", "USC00368888", "USC00368905", 
"USC00369298", "USC00369367", "USC00369408", "USC00369823", "USR0000PALL", 
"USW00003761", "USW00004726", "USW00004751", "USW00004787", "USW00004843", 
"USW00013739", "USW00014711", "USW00014712", "USW00014736", "USW00014737", 
"USW00014751", "USW00014762", "USW00014770", "USW00014777", "USW00014778", 
"USW00014860", "USW00054737", "USW00054782", "USW00054786", "USW00054789", 
"USW00054792", "USW00093778", "USW00094732", "USW00094823"), class = "factor"), 
    AVGTRANGE = c(22.1333333333333, 21.3333333333333, 24.3703703703704, 
    19.8, 22.3666666666667, 20.68, 23.35, 21.4333333333333, 25.75, 
    23.4333333333333, 23.6428571428571, 26.4333333333333, 27.551724137931, 
    25.3448275862069, 25.0666666666667, 26.6842105263158, 23.4444444444444, 
    29.6, 23.3, 30.2631578947368, 27.0454545454545, 25.9333333333333, 
    24.2083333333333, 27.448275862069, 28.2333333333333, 21.4666666666667, 
    24.1111111111111, 25.7333333333333, 23.8571428571429, 21.6, 
    26.08, 26.2916666666667, 27.1034482758621, 28.3666666666667, 
    27.9259259259259, 23.6, 25.7, 26.3666666666667, 26.0344827586207, 
    20.2666666666667, 23.0909090909091, 27.2727272727273, 25.9666666666667, 
    24.8214285714286, 20.2413793103448, 24.0333333333333, 20.6333333333333, 
    26.0344827586207, 22.6, 29.0333333333333, NA, 25.625, 19.0333333333333, 
    18.7666666666667, 21.0689655172414, 22, 24.1333333333333, 
    25.0333333333333, 24.0666666666667, 24.3666666666667, 20.7333333333333, 
    32.5, 26.6666666666667, NA, 22.2666666666667, 25.1333333333333, 
    27.1481481481481, 22.7, 24.4827586206897, 21.6071428571429, 
    20.8461538461538, 29.9333333333333, 17.3928571428571, 26.2666666666667, 
    23.84, 23.1481481481481, 23.8275862068966, 26.9, 26.7931034482759, 
    25.3636363636364, NA, 23.5333333333333, 27.3571428571429, 
    17.2, 24.5, 22.0666666666667, NA, 23.8333333333333, 26.5172413793103, 
    27.6551724137931, 21.2307692307692, 26.5384615384615, 19.5, 
    20.8, 25.3, 18.6666666666667, 25.2758620689655, 23.8333333333333, 
    24.3461538461538, 27.6551724137931, 25.7666666666667, 24, 
    26.0344827586207, 24.6, 28.7333333333333, 27.7, 20.1034482758621, 
    18.6071428571429, 26.1785714285714, 22.5714285714286, 22.6071428571429, 
    17.1785714285714, 19.3571428571429, 21.6071428571429, 24.4285714285714, 
    23.6071428571429, 21.6785714285714, 19.9642857142857, 25.2142857142857, 
    22.7241379310345, 23.0357142857143, 17.8928571428571, 22.2962962962963, 
    21.2857142857143, 21.8571428571429, 21, 25.6428571428571, 
    25.6071428571429, 19.4444444444444, 22.6785714285714), LAT = c(40.6971, 
    40.5361, 40.5227, 40.4949, 41.3585, 40.8209, 40.8619, 39.9355, 
    41.0072, 40.3803, 40.3916, 41.8975, 40.8415, 41.6516, 41.5217, 
    39.848, 39.9353, 41.9301, 40.1468, 41.0489, 41.1922, 39.7994, 
    39.9969, 41.3575, 41.775, 41.7391, 41.9903, 40.2258, 40.46, 
    40.1275, 41.5216, 40.4681, 40.50194, 40.0136, 40.71306, 41.1184, 
    41.4004, 39.8815, 41.5631, 40.0962, 40.5513, 40.9666, 40.2305, 
    39.78333, 40.5511, 39.77056, 40.2817, 40.5972, 41.4992, 41.6767, 
    40.0499, 40.1167, 41.4234, 40.1692, 40.3333, 40.8223, 40.9474, 
    40.5864, 41.64583, 41.131, 40.8344, 40.3391, 39.7808, 41.6725, 
    40.6475, 40.5319, 40.412, 40.61417, 40.1482, 40.075, 39.8, 
    41.9245, 39.9587, 40.8729, 40.12, 41.7394, 39.7275, 41.8157, 
    40.6515, 41.589, 40.9248, 41.3299, 41.4196, 39.8958, 40.5101, 
    40.683, 40.7831, 40.335, 40.05889, 41.05583, 39.8582, 41.8162, 
    40.5711, 40.7933, 41.40389, 41.008, 40.8532, 41.8975, 41.4792, 
    41.63, 41.7511, 41.84667, 39.89861, 41.7004, 40.0417, 41.4864, 
    39.8593, 40.31611, 41.8, 41.17833, 41.62639, 39.87327, 40.1962, 
    40.36667, 40.29639, 40.64985, 40.21722, 40.35472, 40.82056, 
    41.3336, 41.2433, 42.0803, 40.12028, 40.23833, 40.33, 41.13889, 
    41.04667, 39.91806, 40.08194, 40.4846), LONG = c(-75.2042, 
    -79.8152, -78.3694, -78.4667, -77.9262, -76.4983, -75.6428, 
    -77.2577, -76.4482, -76.0274, -79.8594, -78.7144, -79.9163, 
    -76.8463, -77.4478, -79.5898, -77.6394, -79.297, -79.8986, 
    -77.9411, -79.4361, -79.3665, -79.5963, -79.2172, -78.0417, 
    -77.971, -77.1567, -77.1894, -76.8703, -79.4058, -76.4043, 
    -78.7289, -80.0833, -78.3653, -79.5144, -75.7277, -79.8305, 
    -77.3506, -78.6014, -75.7513, -80.2167, -78.5871, -75.4354, 
    -79.9166, -75.9913, -77.0325, -76.8703, -79.1186, -80.4681, 
    -78.8036, -76.2742, -76.4333, -76.4933, -79.1411, -76.4667, 
    -75.6962, -76.8786, -77.5692, -80.425, -77.4336, -76.1352, 
    -79.8604, -79.041, -75.0641, -80.3861, -80.2172, -79.7245, 
    -79.7191, -74.953, -76.0717, -76.05, -78.0072, -75.1728, 
    -78.2161, -75.5011, -75.4465, -79.913, -78.2873, -78.5551, 
    -75.3303, -79.2825, -77.7381, -78.7493, -76.3948, -79.5459, 
    -79.6684, -76.8617, -75.313, -77.5213, -80.06, -77.4774, 
    -80.4249, -75.2781, -77.8672, -78.0183, -75.1876, -76.7891, 
    -77.1419, -79.4432, -79.693, -76.443, -79.1494, -80.1655, 
    -77.3871, -78.5278, -79.1025, -75.7861, -78.8338, -78.6333, 
    -78.8988, -80.215, -75.2267, -76.7724, -75.9666, -78.3202, 
    -75.4477, -76.8513, -79.9216, -76.8641, -75.7269, -76.9217, 
    -80.1824, -76.2944, -75.5572, -75.1225, -75.3794, -78.4116, 
    -76.8741, -75.0111, -80.2144)), .Names = c("STATION", "AVGTRANGE", 
"LAT", "LONG"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-130L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x2a40128>, sorted = "STATION")
```

Comment: can you provide your data with `dput` rather than `head`

Comment: @Bulat Add your data request.

Comment: in addition to my answer I think this behaviour is a bug. I would raise it as bug here: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure what your are trying to achieve with the geom_raster, as your data does not seem to fit the purpose.

Consider the outputs of dot plot:

```
gg <- ggplot(data = locs, aes(x = LONG, y = LAT, colour = AVGTRANGE)) +
  geom_point()
  #geom_raster(aes(fill=AVGTRANGE), interpolate=TRUE)
gg 

data(faithfuld)
gg <- ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions, colour = density)) +
  geom_point()
  #geom_raster(aes(fill = density), interpolate = TRUE)
gg
```

I have also tried `geom_contour` on your data and it does not work:

```
gg <- ggplot(data = locs, aes(x = LONG, y = LAT, z = AVGTRANGE)) +
  geom_contour()
gg
```

UPDATE

I have checked the code of the `geom_raster` and the reason it tries to create the giant plot is that resolution of the plot is based on the minimal distance between points. As some of the points in your data are quite close to each other size of the matrix is so large.

If you round LAT and LONG to 2 digits code works.

```
locs$LAT <- round(locs$LAT, 0)
locs$LONG <- round(locs$LONG, 0)
```

[image]

Comment: I was trying to create a gradient heatmap, where things are shaded to show the change between 2 points.

Comment: @HSchmale, the better solution is to use kriging to generate an evenly spaced raster from your points before passing it to ggplot.